# Why is my donut glowing?

Tags: node-editor

After i went and redid the node tutorial, my donut started glowing. Before, the donut look completly fine, so i dont think it is a lighting issue. Other people who had this problem had the viewer thing on but i dont. This is the rendered version of the donut. (Also why is my donut so spiky?)
link: https://pasteall.org/blend/f6c0f7e112c94e039fc5b705c1ceea3e
[image][image]

Comment: Your donut is likely "glowing" because you connected it directly to the Material Output without using a shader (Principled BSDF, for example) first. The donut is "spiky" because you likely have your displacement scale too high.

Comment: Looking at your nodes, now you've posted the image, I'm no longer sure.... What happens if you turn off the subsurface scattering?

Comment: Unclamped mix soft light?

Comment: maybe share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 1):

Your light is a little high (300W or so is adequate for that distance), and you have a lot of subsurface scattering going on which is producing some weird effects on the spiky edges (which Christopher has correctly diagnosed), the subsurface radius could probably be .1 or .05 for all of the channels.

By the way, your textures didn't pack, so I'm just using a solid color here.  Yours will look better than this with your painted texture.

[image]

If the problem persists, you might look at the values of the color coming out of the image node, and use a *Hue/Saturation* node to level it out.